# Windows Phone - MVVM Light - Multiple ViewModel in a single page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I am new to Windows Phone development.
I am writing an application for Windows Phone 8 using MVVM Light Toolkit.
I have a MainPage with longlistselector navigating to the details page with the relaycommand and everything is good.

Now in the detail page I have to fill out the UI controls with the binding context received from the MailPage (selecteditem of the longlistselector). My problem is that I have in the detail page and which selecteditem should be bound to the data context received from the mainpage.

Just to give an example in the mainpage I have the lostlingselector bound to a list of task objects of the mainviewmodel; every task have its own category which could be selected from the availabe task categories. How could I approach this? Is it possible to bound the ItemSource of the ListPicker control in the detail page to a different viewmodel and the SelectedItem of the same control to the proprties Category of the default viewmodel (selected task object)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new view with it's own viewmodel and pass the data between viewmodels using the MVVM Light Messenger class.

Something like:

```
public class DetailsViewModel
{    
    public DetailsViewModel()
    {

        Messenger.Default.Register<Item>(this, "ItemDetails", i=> ViewItemDetails(i));
    }

    public void ViewItemDetails(Item i)
    {            
       //Now you can bind it to your UI
    }
}
```

And pass the object from your main viewmodel just like this (ItemDetails it's just a token to identify the listeners)

```
Messenger.Default.Send<Item>(SelectedItem, "ItemDetails");
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really mess up with bindings in between different `ViewModel`. To setup interaction between viewmodel's you can use `Messnger` from MvvmLight toolkit, inject it in both objects and define proper pub-sub relations.

```
public class FirstViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private IMesseger messenger;

   ...

   public FirstViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
   {
       this.messenger = messenger;
   }

   public Item SelectedItem
   {
       get
       {
            return this.selectedItem;
       }

       set
       {
            this.selectedItem = value;
            this.messenger.Send(new GenericMessage<Item>(this.selectedItem));
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
       }
   }
}

public class SecondViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private IMesseger messenger;

   ...

   public SecondViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
   {
       this.messenger = messeger;
       this.messenger.Register<GenericMessage<Item>>(this, this.HandleItemSelected);
   }

   ...
}
```

So after sharing same instance of messenger between two VM's you'll have desired functionality with loosely coupled relations which is good from testing perspectives.